# FirstOrDefault() causing Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using an ASP.NET MVC 5, EntityFramerwork 6 and MySQL. I also use Ninject (however I don't think this error is related to DI). I have seen a lot of questions with this exception, but was not able to find the issue with my code.

I am trying to fix the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
> operation may not execute.

One thing to keep in mind is that this error occurs very occasionally, maybe 2 times a day and so far I have only seen this error when the **UserAgent is a bot** (so far I have seen this error with 2 different bots)

From the StackTrace, I know the exception is thrown in `AdPersister` class, this method:

```
public class AdPersister<TEntity> : IAdPersister<TEntity>
    where TEntity : AdBase
{
    private readonly AdRepository<TEntity> _adRepository;
    private readonly IAdImageFiler _adImageFiler;

    public AdPersister(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _adRepository = new AdRepository<TEntity>(dbContext);
        _adImageFiler = AdImagePersisterFactory.CreateAdImagePersister();
    }

    public TEntity GetActiveAd(long adBaseId)
    {
        TEntity ad = _adRepository.GetActiveAd(adBaseId);
        if (ad != null)
        {
            LoadImages(ad);
        }

        return ad;
    }

    // more code...
}
```

The above function calls `AdRepository` class, this method:

```
internal class AdRepository<TEntity> : AdRepositoryBase
    where TEntity : AdBase
{
    public AdRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) 
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public TEntity GetActiveAd(long adBaseId)
    {
        return _dbContext.AdBase.OfType<TEntity>()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(r => r.Address)
                    .Include(r => r.UserProfile)
                    .Where(r => r.IsActive == true && r.AdBaseId == adBaseId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // more code...
}
```

This is the Ninject biding that I use for `AdPersister`:

```
Bind(typeof(IAdPersister<>)).To(typeof(AdPersister<>)).InRequestScope();
```

I am also using [EntityFramework DynamicFilters](https://entityframework-dynamicfilters.net/overview), to exclude the soft-deleted records:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (AdBase ab) => ab.IsDeleted, false);
}
```

Here is the Exception message:

```
Url: http://www.MySite.co.nz/car/display/52633 

UserAgent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) 

Message: The underlying provider failed on Open. 

InnerException: 
---------------
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. 

    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) 
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext() 
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.get_ConnectionString() 
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) 
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() 

Exception: 
----------
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. 
    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) 
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext() 
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.get_ConnectionString() 
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) 
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__0() 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) 
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__31_0() 
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() 
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
    at MySite.Infrastructure.Main.UmbrellaServices.AdPersister`1.GetActiveAd(Int64 adBaseId) 
        in C:\MySite\MySite.source\MySite.Infrastructure.Main\UmbrellaServices\AdPersister.cs:line 35 
            at MySite.Application.Main.Services.AdService`2.GetActiveAd(Int64 adBaseId) 
        in C:\MySite\MySite.source\MySite.Application.Main\Services\AdService.cs:line 40 
            at MySite.Web.Controllers.CarController.Display(Int64 adBaseId)
```

### Update (Re John Wu's comment)

I need to clarify that I am using a multi-host connection string, so something like this:

```
Server=host1, host2, host3; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Connector/Net is supposed to load balance the connections to MySQL DB. There used to be a bug with Connector/NET with multi-host ConnectionString ([81650](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81650), [88962](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88962))

Connector/NET fixed this issue in version 8.0.19 (https://insidemysql.com/) and that's the version that I am using.

As pointed by John Wu, this error is happening in Connector/Net source code, I believe [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/8.0/MySQL.Data/src/Failover/FailoverManager.cs). I think this is a new bug.

Comment: Is your repository being shared between requests? Basically, this sounds like concurrency between separate requests, which: don't do that

Comment: If you inspect the stack trace, the error has to do with computation of the connection string based on a dictionary and is upstream of any attempt to actually use the database. My guess is that something is happening on your server that modifies the connection string data while the application is running, and once in a while it makes its modifications at the exact moment you're trying to open a connection.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I updated my question, a new `Repository` is being instantiated in the constructor of `AdPersister` and `AdPersister` scope is `InRequestScope`.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. In particular I'd be interested to see if any of the repository usage is async or within a `Task.Run`.

Comment: @JohnWu: I have updated the question, I am using a multi-host connection string.

Comment: @mjwills: As you can see the repository is not `async` and I am not using `Task.Run`... As I have explained I am getting this exception very occasionally when a bot crawls the site... it would have been nice if I could reproduce the issue ;-)

Comment: That is literally _all_ of the code? Nothing else uses the repository?

Comment: Could you share `Display` with us?